# Elegant code for binary addition?

Tags: scheme, racket

I just wrote the function add-registers for binary addition of two n-bit registers in Racket (using bit-add function as a helper):

```
(define (bit-add x y c)
  (values (bitwise-xor x y c) (bitwise-ior (bitwise-and x y)
                                           (bitwise-and x c)
                                           (bitwise-and y c))))

(define (add-registers xs ys)
  (let ([carry 0])
    (values (reverse (for/list ([b1 (reverse xs)] [b2 (reverse ys)])
                       (let-values ([(nb nc) (bit-add b1 b2 carry)])
                         (set! carry nc)
                         nb)))
            carry)))
```

But I found my code pretty ugly. So I wonder if this could be written more concisely and elegant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a new version of `add-registers` that looks somewhat nicer:

```
(define (add-registers xs ys)
  (for/fold ([carry 0] [bs empty])
     ([b1 (reverse xs)] [b2 (reverse ys)])
     (define-values (nb nc) (bit-add b1 b2 carry))
     (values nc (cons nb bs))))
```